# SQL Database Import From Excel to MVC Site

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp.net-mvc, database-design, import

I have an excel spreadsheet that I need to convert to an SQL database for an ASP.NET MVC website.
An example of the spread sheet is:

[image]

I have ID's for each of the rows as well (not pictured).

The numbers on the spreadsheet are items that contain the listed item (the row ending in .htm).

My database idea was as follows:

[image]

My ultimate goal on the MVC website is to search by these numbers to get a list of the .htm rows that have that number as an option.

How would I go about importing the data to a database to achieve this?
I'm not even sure how to approach this. Any tips/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems, you managed to import the data - and are stuck going forward. Are the numbers representing some stuff, which is (to be) stored (with some detail) in the **numbered_item** table - but not shown in the picture, which is part of your posting? From what is available so far, I'd suggest, you need to move all the numbers from **htm_items** to **htm_numbered**. If you were adding (i) the (current) create table statements, (ii) some sample data (as text rather than a picture), and possibly (iii) examples of queries with the expected output, it would be easier to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by making two tables. It was not an elegant solution, but it works.  The first table(htm_items) had ID and ItemName as the columns,  table 2 (numbered_items) had ID and 34 columns numbered Col1, Col2, Col3...Col33, Col34 for the "items" that are listed in my data.  Based on my spreadsheet my data for the second table would be as follows:
**ID**: 1    **Col1:** 1789    **Col2:** 1814    **Col3:**1815   **Col4:**1817   **Col5-Col34:** null 
*...*

Once I imported that data to my website, I wrote a LINQ query in my controller to pull up the data I needed.

```
 var results = (from x in db.htm_Items
                join i in db.numbered_Items on x.ID equals i.ID
                where i.C1 == id ||
                                 i.C2 == id ||
                                 i.C3 == id ||
                                 i.C4 == id ||
                                 i.C5 == id ||
                                 i.C6 == id ||
                                 i.C7 == id ||
                                 i.C8 == id ||
                                ...
                                 i.C33 == id ||
                                 i.C34 ==id
                                select x);
```

Like I said, not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me.